# Unable to deploy Orchard Azure project - YSOD fresh off sources

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I am deploying Orchard to Azure cloud services (webrole) without any code changes to the official stable release. However, when I navigate to that freshly deployed Orchard cloud service (webrole), I see a YSOD with `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`.

As a work around, if I enable Local Copy=True (i.e. modify source), then this specific YSOD goes but is replaced by another one for `msshrtmi`). But more importantly, I'm able to deploy the pre-built downloaded Orchard Azure (1.7, prebuilt off same GIT src tag), without issues, so I'd rather fix the root issue than go down a rabbit hole of workarounds and drift further from the official sources.

How I'm running into this issue:

1. Download source from GIT (http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest, I used  `commit 5e0c26f73cf5`, )
2. Run `ClickToBuildAzurePackage.cmd` script
3. Edit `buildazure\Stage\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` to put in connection string's to point to the real Azure storage account (vs Local Storage).
4. Deploy both the files in `buildazure\Stage` to Azure via the windowsazure.com portal
5. Navigate to site (eg: http://OrchardTest.cloudapp.net)
6. Enjoy the yellow-screen-of-death :(

Our local build system:

- Windows 8, x64
- VS2012.3
- Azure SDK 1.7, 1.8, 2.0

**Question:**

Has anyone deployed to Azure successfully? Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should never be a need to CopyLocal True on the Azure Service Runtime. That is automatically included in the package, defined by your Cloud Services project (In this case, Orchard.Azure.CloudService). And actually, I could imagine that CopyLocal True might cause issues if the bin contains a different version of the Service Runtime than the Azure package was built under.

Orchard Azure uses the Azure 2.0 libraries. It shows that you have the 2.0 SDK installed because you can compile the Orchard.Azure.CloudService project to make a package. Cloud Service projects have different a project guid for each version of the Azure tools, so without the v2.0 SDK, it would be an unknown project type. However, with your Orchard website picking up ServiceRuntime v1.7, it seems that something is amiss with your local environment, as it should still identify with v2.0.

When you open Orchard.Azure.sln, check the Properties on the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime reference within the Orchard.Azure.Web project. What is the version that Visual Studio lists on that reference? It should be 2.0.0. If it does not, my best recommendation would be to reinstall the 2.0 Libraries.

The deployment steps as you have defined work just fine with no YSOD. I successfully tried it just before writing this; it did not reproduce your issue.

Comment: The key was `my best recommendation would be to reinstall the 2.0 Libraries`. I uninstalled all the SDKs (1.7,1.8,2.0) rebooted and then installed 2.0. I still have to build via the `ClickToBuildAzurePackage.cmd` script as builds within VS2012 are failing with `None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardShell' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:` - but that's another issue (and less of a showstopper). Thanks.

Comment: To add, even the issue with VS2012 builds failing was resolved once I picked up the latest changes over the past few days made to the development branch (i.e. `1.x` branch). All's good!